# Immutable JS - how to preserve Type and get immutability when converting a deeply nested JS object?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Working on a React, Redux + Typescript project, I am trying to add Immutable JS to the stack.

I started with working on a large nested object that could really use being safer as an immutable data structure.

```
import { Record, fromJS } from "immutable";

const obj = {
  name: "werwr",
  overview: {
    seasons: {
      2017: [{ period: 1, rates: 2 }]
    }
  }
};
// -- Using fromJS
const objJS = fromJS(obj);
const nObj = objJS.getIn(["overview", "seasons", "2017"]);
console.log(nObj); // I get an immutable list cool!

// -- Using Record, infer the type
const objRecord = Record(obj)();
const nRec = objRecord.getIn(["overview", "seasons", "2017"]);
console.log(nRec); // but I get a JS array

// -- Using both
const makeRec = Record(objJS);
const bothRecord = makeRec({ name: "name" });
console.log(bothRecord); // fails
```

Runnable code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-panini-9bpgn?file=/src/index.ts

1. using fromJS. The conversion works well and deep but I lose all
   type information.
2. using a Record. It keeps track of the type but nested arrays are
   still mutable.
3. passing the converted object into a Record and manually add the type but I ran into an error: Cannot read property 'get' of
   undefined

Whats the proper way to convert such an object to a fully immutable data structure while not loosing the type? Thanks!

Comment: runnable code snippets are convenient, but in order to create preservable QA, please include code in the question here on SO

Comment: the error in the link can be fixed by updating the line to `const makeRec = Record<Obj>(obj);`. However, you will probably get more attention if you include some code in the question along side the working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes to construct deep structures.

```
interface IRole {
  name: string;
  related: IRole[];
}

const roleRecord = Record({
  name: '',
  related: List<Role>(),
});

class Role extends roleRecord {
  name: string;
  related: List<Role>;
  constructor(config: IRole) {
    super(Object.assign({}, config, {
      related: config.related && List(config.related.map(r => new Role(r))),
    }));
  }
}

const myRole = new Role({
  name: 'President',
  related: [
    {name: 'VP', 
    related:[
      {name: 'AVP', 
      related: []}
    ]}
  ]});
```

With this type of structure, `myRole` will be all nested `Role` classes.

NOTE: I will add a bit of caution, we have been using this structure in a production application for almost 4 years now (angular, typescript, redux), and I added the immutablejs for safety from mutated actions and stores. If I had to do it over, the strict immutable store and actions that comes with NGRX would be my choice. Immutablejs is great at what it does, but the complexity it adds to the app is a trade off (Especially for onboarding new/greener coders).

Comment: glorious, 4 days nothing and then we  both write basically the same within 7minutes :-)
We had the same experience with a React app, but the alternatives so far do not convince me either.

Comment: ha. I try to write one answer each work day. This was just the one I chose today. I don't even think I noticed it was 4 days old. I agree with your assessment of `Record` s and how the nesting can get a bit laborious. In the end, I don't think Immutable fully supports typescript. Maybe what we really need is an `Immutable-Ts` :)

Comment: Really tho, Immutable in TypeScript looks like you want to highlight the syntactical downsides of TS and Immutable at the same time. We use it in some JS apps and there it's fine, but TS just looks super stupid

Answer (score 0):

`Record` is a factory for Record-Factories. As such, the argument should be an object template (aka default values), not actual data! ([see docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record)).

```
const MyRecord = Record({
  name: "werwr",
  overview: null
});

const instance = MyRecord(somedata);
```

As you already noticed, the Record factory will not transform data to immutable. If you want to do that, you have to either do it manually with `Maps` and `Lists`, `fromJS` or the `constructor` of records.

The last approach is a bit weird, because then your record factory suddendly becomes a class:

```
const SeasonRecord = Record({
  period: null, rates: null
})

class MyRecord extends Record({
    name: "default_name",
    seasons: Map()
}, 'MyRecord') {
    constructor(values = {}, name) {
        if(values.seasons) {
          // straight forward Map of seasons: 
          // values = fromJS(values);

          // Map of sub-records
          values.seasons = Object.entries(values.seasons).reduce(
            (acc, [year, season]) => { 
              acc[year] = SeasonRecord(season);
              return acc;
            }, {});
          values.seasons = Map(values.seasons);
        }
        super(values, name);
    }
}

const x = new MyRecord({
  seasons: {
      2017: { period: 1, rates: 2 }
    }
})
console.log('period of 2017', x.seasons.get('2017').period)
```

I strongly suggest to not use unecessarily nest objects (record -> overview -> season) as it makes everything more complicated (and if you use large amounts of records, it might impact performance).

My general recommendation for Records is to keep them as flat as possible. The shown nesting of records allows to use the property access syntax instead of `get`, but is too tendious most of the time. Simply doing fromJS() for the values of a record and then use `getIn` is easier.

Comment: I agree with dube, records are best used with flat data sets.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers and the very valuable comments. I am still really on the fence about adding Immutable Js to the stack, as I sometimes feel that deep cloning an object, or Object.freeze could be enough for the value I try to add... Immutable JS doesn't do great with TS out of the box... I try to keep my code as functional as possible... so adding a class looks like a good solution but doesn't feel right...

Comment: The best answer I found so far is typing Maps: 'Back to square one: typing Maps' in https://blog.mayflower.de/6630-typescript-redux-immutablejs.html

Comment: Deep-Cloning might have a bad performance with large datasets, e.g. when you have many different lists that essentially reference the same base data. Immutable will shine there. Don't underestimate the amount of work involved in "doing it myself" (e.g. freeze is shallow!). But there are multiple well-established immutability libraries. I never checked because I worked mostly in non-TS projects, but I am sure some are better suited for TS.